# Add kick option to mobile chat UI

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, mobile-web, kick-mute

The kick-mute feature in chat is... Wonderful. Instead of letting rudeness or idiocy derail a conversation, savvy room owners and moderators can quietly remove the disruptive person from the room for a short time, and continue chatting without breaking stride. The person responsible gets a polite reminder to be considerate, and the rest of the folks in the room don't have to listen to someone being berated in public.

**...unless the mods/owners happen to be chatting on mobile.**

The new mobile theme, wonderful though it is, lacks a "kick-mute" option. Posts have a flag option (though no mod-flag option) and a delete option, but tapping a user just takes you to their profile.

Kicking therefore requires:

1. Switch to the full-site theme
2. Tap the username (probably have to zoom in for this unless you have very small fingers).
3. Find the menu that popped up (if you zoomed in, it definitely *won't* be next to the username you tapped)
4. Tap kick-mute (might have to zoom in again if you zoomed out to find the pop-up)
5. Flip back to mobile theme (zoom all the way out and target an unreadable link in the bottom-right sidebar).

That's... Hard to do without a significant break in the conversation, during which things may well have escalated.

Comment: This. I happen to have small enough fingers that I can happily use the full site on my iPad, and thus am able to kick-mute from there - but from my phone, it's nigh-on impossible.

Comment: Why stop there?  Let us set timeouts and move messages too!  Moving is especially painful, since while you can access it with the desktop view it's essentially unusable without a mouse.

Comment: Certainly wouldn't mind having *everything*, @davidism... But kicking is definitely something I feel needs to be accessible very, very quickly.

Comment: Yes, I'd find it very convenient, and better to start somewhere with unifying the two views.  Let's not forget just adding a documented chat API too. ;-)

Comment: (trivia: @davidism kicks more than anyone else anywhere on the network, so when he says "yes", that's the voice of experience talking)

Comment: But mobile phones are so tiny, and some fingers are so big. Many times people aimed for edit button but hit delete instead. What if you kicked someone by accident?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the words of the world's most fickle Genie, "Your wish is sometimes in line with what I happen to do"; this option is now available (for room owners) via the pop-down menu that you get when you click/push/touch/whatever on a message. If it doesn't appear immediately (because there are too many options), click the "..." expander. You will get a confirmation prompt before it does anything too nasty.

Here's me about to kick Samo (because: reasons, amiright?):

[image]

(ignore the profiling data top-left; I was too lazy to disable mini-profiler  for the grab)

Comment: Could you also add an option to the site to kick those users who use non-freehand red ovals in their posts?

Comment: @Bart everyone's a critic...

Comment: Question: Could this also be made available through the user sidebar you get when opening the list of participants? I find that list to be a more expected way to kick a user. After all the user is kicked and not the message...

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow my view was that you're likely to be *responding* to a message or messages, plus that UI already had a "do something" metaphor / mechanism - the user fly-out doesn't, currently. We could add it; let's see  how folks feel.

Comment: It could allow something like a "usercard" in the mobile view. Hiding messages and Ignoring a user should also go there (just like on desktop). I think these features are quite useful to keep the peace in a chatroom...

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow that's a more significant  set of UI changes; I don't disagree with your point, but being realistic: that's going to take more input from folks